# Exit command prompt after opening a java swing application

Tags: java, swing, command

I am invoking a java swing program from command program and after executing the java program the console remains open. My bat file contains :

```
set Gantt_Generator_v5.0="C:\Program Files\GANTT_GENERATOR_V5.0"
java -jar %Gantt_Generator_v5.0%\GANTT_GENERATOR_V5.0.jar "C:\Program Files\GANTT_GENERATOR_V5.0\test\Parameter_File.csv" FALSE
exit
```

When I close the command prompt the java application quits.

**Tried options :** changed the extension from **.bat** to **.cmd** but didn't work for me.

Any other solutions?

Comment: Try using `javaw` instead of `java`

Comment: Didn't work @MadProgrammer..

Comment: i have a bat which starts with java and without exit at the end and it closes, when the java-application closes

Comment: @duffy356 : This is what I don't want. I want the command prompt to either **hide** or **exit** after invoking the java program.

Comment: Given you added the 'Swing' tag, I suggest to avoid the command-line altogether and launch the app. using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  You could set it up to consume CSV files, then when the user double clicks one, it would be passed the path.  The only thing you'd need to prompt the user for is the boolean at the end of the command seen above.  What does the boolean mean, what does it control?

Comment: @AndrewThompson : Yes we can run the executable JAR directly but the issue here is I want to pass parameter to the Main class which cannot be passed while creating the JAR using eclipse, hence using command line to invoke the JAR. And the boolean here is used not to delete the .csv file after executing and exiting the program. If you put it as TRUE than the .csv file (argument) will be deleted from the specified location.

Comment: Do you control the code for 'Gantt Generator' API?  I'm thinking Eclipse has nothing to do with it (from the POV of deployment, which is what I thought we were discussing).

Comment: Nope I have built one application which is named Gantt Generator. And while creating JAR using eclipse it specifically says that the arguments will not be a part of JAR.

Comment: *"If you put it as TRUE than the .csv file (argument) will be deleted from the specified location."*  What if it is omitted entirely?  What does it default to?

Comment: *"I have built one application which is named Gantt Generator."*  Right.  Thanks for confirming.  OK - is it intended to be used by other people as well, or is it just for your use?

Comment: The very fact an app. with a GUI has a parameter for deleting the file it is told to process, is very unusual, and slightly disturbing to me.  What if the user of the app. decides midway through running the app. that they want to retain the CSV file after all?

Comment: Yes it is intended to use by other people as well. But why does this question come here?? If the parameter is not passed and omitted than the application will not run and exit immediately.

Comment: If javaw doesn't work, try "start javaw ..."

Comment: Final Script is : 
`set Gantt_Generator_v5.0="C:\Program Files  (x86)\GANTT_GENERATOR_V5.0"
    start javaw -jar %Gantt_Generator_v5.0%\GANTT_GENERATOR_V5.0.jar  "C:\Program Files (x86)\GANTT_GENERATOR_V5.0\test\Parameter_File.csv" FALSE`

Comment: .. ***should*** be asked.

Comment: @AndrewThompson : Thanks for elaborating on my doubts. Have added my final script as answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

used "**START JAVAW...**" so the final Script is :

```
set Gantt_Generator_v5.0="C:\Program Files (x86)\GANTT_GENERATOR_V5.0" 
start javaw -jar %Gantt_Generator_v5.0%\GANTT_GENERATOR_V5.0.jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\GANTT_GENERATOR_V5.0\test\Parameter_File.csv" FALSE
```